# Sitecore: purpose of PublishingTargets when publishing from code

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

When I publish a Sitecore item from my C# code, I can do something like this:

```
var po = new PublishOptions(masterDatabase,
    webDatabase,
    PublishMode.SingleItem,
    Language.Parse("nl-NL"),
    DateTime.Now,
    publishingTargets);

var p = new Publisher(po);
p.Options.RootItem = subject;
p.Options.Deep = true;
p.Publish();
```

My question: what exactly is the purpose of the PublishingTargets property of the PublishOptions class, which I provide as the constructor's last parameter?

And what would happen if I don't provide any publishing targets (but still provide a target database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Publishing` section of any Sitecore item there is a `Publishing Targets` field:

[image]

If this field has any of the targets selected, it will be only published if that target is also passed in the `Publish Options`.

This means that you can create second publishing target and assign it to `Item A`. If you do this, `Item A` will never be published from `master` to `web` unless you pass that second publishing target as a parameter to the `Publish Options`.

If `Publishing Targets` field is empty (and by default it is), that last parameter is not used.